# Jquery animation with multiply elements loops in firefox

Tags: jquery

I am trying to resize navigation with logo and some buttons on scroll. I have problem with Firefox. If user use this several times, all other animations wont execute until this is finished. Have tried with .finish() and .stop( true, true)

```
function resizeTopSmall() {
    $('#sticky-top').stop().animate({height: '60px'}, { duration: 200, queue: false });
    $('#top nav a, #social a').stop().animate({'font-size':'0.9em', 'padding':'25px 10px 22px'}, { duration: 200, queue: false });
    $('#logo').stop().animate({height:'60px', width:'240px'}, { duration: 200, queue: false });
    $('#logo img').stop().animate({width:'240px'}, { duration: 200, queue: false });
    $('#logo a').css({padding:'15px 0 0'});

}   
function resizeTopBig() {
    $('#sticky-top').stop().animate({height: '120px'}, { duration: 200, queue: false });
    $('#top nav a, #social a').stop().animate({'font-size':'1em', 'padding':'50px 10px 22px'}, { duration: 200, queue: false });
    $('#logo').stop().animate({height:'120px', width:'125px'}, { duration: 200, queue: false });
    $('#logo img').stop().animate({width:'700px'}, { duration: 200, queue: false });
    $('#logo a').css({padding:'5px 0 0'});
}
```

BTW: I placed that code in $(window).on("load scroll resize",function(e){...
Using: 1.11.1 jQuery and UI

Comment: Why don't you use css animation?

Comment: Too much code? I like to keep it clear and narrow, but it seams that I will have to

Comment: Jquery `animate`is slow though.

Comment: Ervald, zou are right!. Will do that via CSS